# How do I configure fcitx googlepinyin IM?

Tags: google, input, chinese

I've installed the fcitx googlepinyin wrapper IM, opened the "fcitx configure tool" and can't seem to add any input methods. Am I missing something?

Any other recommendations for a pinyin input method would be appreciated.

Bayka

Answer (score 0):

Is fcitx running? Which version?

fcitx-googlepinyin is not really supported now (see the bold text on it's googlecode homepage). fcitx-pinyin is good enough for me and fcitx-sunpinyin is also a good option.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. After restarting ubuntu a few times nothing happened, then I logged out and back in again and presto! It's working.
Solved